# Semantic querying of local data

Tags: images, rdf, sparql

Just got told to find some specific pictures for a calendar as a gift. I have thousands of pictures and looking through all of them is annoying. I just realized that the requirements of the images could be found by a  sparql query pretty easy. Can I somehow store the image metadata in a database? Even cooler would be if the image could be scraped to determine how many people are in there. Google and facebook do this for sure, is this possible on a desktop too?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can store images with meta-data (E.g. tags) in a database. It is rather trivial thing to do. It won't solve your problem though, as you'll need to visit every picture in your collection to classify them (assign tags to it, such as cat, autumn, water, etc.).

If all you really need to know is how many faces are there in each pictures you might want to check out OpenCV library (to do face detection, not face recognition, as all you need is a number).

If you are after more general classification such as objects, animals, events - you'll need a much more elaborate solution from the area of Machine Learning (check out Cybula for this).

Practically though it will likely be faster for you to go through you collection of some thousands of pictures and assign tags manually using some picture manager application (Picasa used to be able to do this) and later do a search by tags.

Comment: Which database do you mean? Can I query the database using Spaql?

Comment: For example Neo4j database